# AngularJS and SEO - Setting Different Meta Description Tags for each partial?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, seo, meta-tags

For a simple example of my situation, let's say I have a Sign Up partial page ('/signup') and a Sign In ('/signin') partial page.

For the sign up partial, I want the meta tag to be:

```
<meta name="description" content="Sign Up">
```

For the sign in partial, I want the meta tag to be:

```
<meta name="description" content="Sign In">
```

In my main index.html file, I have the ng-view tag is that is nested inside the body tag where the partials will be displayed. Since the partials are inside the body tag and the header tag (where you would normally put metatags for static files) is outside, how do I set Meta Description Tags for each partial using AngularJS?

If anyone could help me with a sample code, that would be great as I am totally stuck. :(

Comment: Have you seen this https://github.com/moonfuse/angular-meta?

Comment: Thanks for the link! It seems like it will do exactly what I need. However,  I am afraid, like skewl84 said, that the search engine crawlers will not be able to detect this javascript code. Can anyone confirm if it will work for SEO purposes? :O

Comment: Crawlers that read javascript (such as google) might be able to detect it, however, for seo, i'd suggest also generating a static version of the site using a crawler so that search engines can index the static version with all of the appropriate meta information.

Answer (score -4):

Are you needing to do this for SEO purposes If yes, don't try to do it via angularjs because the search engine crawlers don't allow any javascript code to be run.

Instead look at implementing the hashbang and server side approach.

Look at this article:
http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html

Comment: Yes, I am needing to do this for SEO purposes. I actually have read  the article and done it, but unfortunately it does not mention about updating particularly the meta description tags. :(

Comment: I'm using the #! hashbang standard setup by Google.

Comment: The hashbang hack is [awful](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs) and was superseded by [the history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) years ago.

Comment: Lately Google has been crawling web pages by rendering javascript.

Comment: http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157